# DAX Count in every date in range

Tags: powerbi, dax

Hello :) In my model I have a fact table:

| FactKey | CreatedDateKey | ClosedDateKey |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 20220101 | 20220601 |

And 2 date dimension: Created Date and Close Date

I would like to create a measure which presents count of FactKey in every date in which key is valid, for instance: 
**Created Date | Count** 
2022-01-01  | 1 
2022-01-02  | 1 
2022-01-03  | 1 
.  | . 
.  | . 
.  | .  
2022-06-01  | 1

Could you please help me to create valid calculation? Thanks in advance!

Comment: how are you going to visualize the result?

Answer (score 1):

```
VAR CurrentDay = SelectedValue(date[date])
VAR filteredFact =
        FILTER(
               ALL(FACT)
               ,AND(
                    [CreatedDateKey]<=CurrentDay
                    ,[ClosedDateKey]>=CurrentDay
               )
         )

RETURN
    COUNTROWS(filterdFact)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that a good option it's to create a calculated column and then a a DAX like this ->

```
 IF(ISBLANK(CreatedDateKey),"",1)
```

What this functions does it's reads the column and checks for nulls, if there's a date inside it will add a 1 to the new column, in the other case it will leave a null

Once you have that result then you can add a KPI Card and then summarize the amount of 1 that you have.

Let me know if this solution works, otherwise I can give further assistance

Comment: But what if CreatedDateKey contains the string "monkey"? Do you assume this is a valid DateKey? I think the question is how to get from a date number to an ISO date!

Comment: Thank you, but I need something different. Iny fact table I have only range- from Created Date to Close Date, but in the visualization I need to show values for every date in range. I wanted to create calculated table and populate dates, but because of the architecture of the solution I can't do it.

Comment: To better clarify I will use HR example: In fact table we have some informations about employee XYZ, start and end date. In Power BI I want to present graph with start date and number of employees, so employee XYZ should be counted in every date between start and end date